# Similar to Self Organization Maps, are all other clustering algorithms "self organizing"?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

From my understanding of the terms:

**Self** means:

- No supervision is required during training.

**Organizing** means:

- To create a topographic ordered map by using unsupervised competitive learning and cooperative learning.
- Competitive: All neurons compete with each  other to become a winning 
      neuron. Mechanism known as ‘Winner take all learning’.
- Cooperative: Neuron dealing with closely related piece of information
  come closer to each other.

**Map** means:

- Neurons in output space attempt to map their weights to conform to the given input data.    OR
- The nodes in a SOM network attempt to become like the inputs presented to them. Because of this mapping,  also called Self Organization Feature Map.

K-means, Hierarchical, DBSCAN all meet the definition of **Self** as it appears for SOM. We can also say they are **Maps**  as there is mapping of input vector to centers. My question is: can we also say whether or not they are **Organizing** as well?

In brief, is the below table correct?[image]

Comment: I see neither the self-organizing aspect ("rearranging" data) nor the map (2d grid) aspect in any of the other algorithms. But I don't think this name is to be read as three features A and B and C. I don't think that table makes sense.

Comment: I get the impression that this is a semantics question, with the complication that these aren't really standard/well-defined terms. It's trying to interpret meanings from the title of some existing method, then map (heh) other methods onto them. It might be more fruitful to skip the interpretation part, and just start with a well defined property of interest. Then, ask whether it applies to specific methods.

Comment: I know the properties of SOM. But 'Self organizing' means  "No supervision is required during training.  SOMs   learn   on  their  own   through   unsupervised competitive learning". Excluding 'Map, are traditional clustering algorithms 'Self organizing'.

Comment: Kmeans just uses one of the data points to represent a cluster. Kohonen contrasts kmeans as "accurate ordering" with SOM's "self-ordering". The SOM rearranges its topology dynamically, hence it is self organizing. "Supervised SOM" means you pass the classes along with the inputs--it's still SOM even if supervised.